# How to send a number (to a computer for action) during call in custom caller application through custom dialer

Tags: java, android

I have tried this

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But, It doesn't send that parameter/number to the caller. like press 1 for this action or press 2 for that action

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  private void makeCall(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String number, boolean addPlus) {
    String prefix = addPlus ? "tel+:" : "tel:";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(prefix + number));
    context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: I want to press the number when operator asks me to press 1 or press 2  during conversation